# AudioContext Oscillator won't play more than once

Tags: javascript, html, audiocontext

I know that you can't play an oscillator more than once, so i wrote a function that creates a new one every time:

```
function playFrequency(f, t0, t1){
    console.log(f, t0, t1);
    var oscillator = self.audioContext.createOscillator();
    oscillator.type = "square";
    oscillator.frequency.value = f;
    oscillator.connect(self.audioContext.destination);
    oscillator.start(t0);
    oscillator.stop(t1);
}
```

But the strange thing is that the function will actually play the sound only once. I can't understand why this happens. Am I not creating a new oscillator every time I call the function?

When I create a function "playFrequency2(f, t0, t1)" which has the exact same code, it will play a sound even after the first function has played the sound. But it won't play the sound when I call it the second time too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the `start` time your passing to your function. Start time is calculated from the `audioContext` `currentTime` which starts when the `audioContext` is created and keep moving forward from then on. So when you start your first sound at 0 for example and then end it at 3, your `audioContext` will keep running after that. So if you call your new sound with same time arguments, it won't play because your `start` time is before `currentTime`. 
You could modify like this:

```
function playFrequency(f, t1){
    console.log(f, t0, t1);
    var oscillator = self.audioContext.createOscillator();
    oscillator.type = "square";
    oscillator.frequency.value = f;
    oscillator.connect(self.audioContext.destination);
    oscillator.start();
    oscillator.stop(self.audioContext.currentTime+t1);
}
```